# Boolean Operators <, >, <= etc

Tags: python

I'm creating a program that calculates a grade and spits out a message like "you got an a (if percentage over 90), b if percentage over 80 etc..I'm not using the operators properly. Can someone please show me the proper format? Thanks!

```
def totals(score_w, score_x, score_y, score_z):
print ("Overall percentage = ", round(score_w + score_x + score_y + score_z), 1)
if round((score_w + score_x + score_y + score_z, 1) > 90.0):
    print("Your grade will be at least: A")
elif round((score_w + score_x + score_y + score_z, 1) (< 90) and (>= 80)):
    print("Your grade will be at least: B")
elif round((score_w + score_x + score_y + score_z, 1) (< 80) and (>= 70)):
    print("Your grade will be at least: C")
```

Comment: Put `round((score_w + score_x + score_y + score_z, 1)` in a variable so you don’t have to repeat it all the time, then rewrite your `if`s to use that variable. The problem might become clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a quick function on my own which does what you want.

Here is what is wrong with your code:

1. You need to indent it properly.
2. This comparison is wrong:
   (< 90) and (>= 80))

You should have something similar to this: (Note: This is a python 2 code)

```
def totals(score_w, score_x, score_y, score_z):
    rnd = round(score_w + score_x + score_y + score_z)
    print "Overall percentage is: " + str(rnd)
    if rnd >= 90.0:
        print "A"
    elif rnd < 90 and rnd >= 80:
        print "B"
    elif rnd < 80 and rnd >= 70:
        print "C"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do

```
round((score_w + score_x + score_y + score_z, 1) (< 90) and (>= 80))
```

But you CAN do this:

```
 80 <= round(score_w + score_x + score_y + score_z, 1) < 90
```

If you want to use the `and` operator here, you will have to write it like this:

```
round(score_w + score_x + score_y + score_z, 1) < 90 and round(score_w + score_x + score_y + score_z, 1) >= 80
```

As suggested, you should put your round function into a var, such as:

```
grade = round(score_w + score_x + score_y + score_z, 1)
```

Then the code will be a much cleaner:

```
if 80 <= grade < 90:
```

or

```
if 80 <= grade and grade < 90:
```

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that one of the comparisons is not actually necessary. The `elif` takes care of skipping scores that were good enough for a higher grade. So the first check can be `grade >= 90`, then the next can be `grade >= 80` without bothering to reconfirm `grade < 90`.